# Referencing a CSS file from another directory

Tags: php, html, css

I'm designing a website but I used a base template that I found and now I'm modifying it. I'm using a web hosting service, so the root directory isn't on my computer. So, inside public_html I have /js/ javascript files and /css/ CSS files. In the root folder I have my home page etc, but I want to put the store's page in /store/storehome.php. I'm using .php so that I can include the header.html and footer.html files which are located in /includes/. All the JS and CSS files are not mine, and I'm just editing them to serve my desires.

The issue is that the storehome.php file will not format correctly. I don't fully understand what it's missing (I'm new to this) but I assume it's not seeing the CSS file.

I've been referencing the CSS through the header file, and it seems to work for the normal root files. This is part of the header file:

```
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mywebsite.com/js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mywebsite.com/js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mywebsite.com/js/init.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mywebsite.com/css/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mywebsite.com/css/style.css" />
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v9.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
```

And no matter what, even if I do /css/style.css or ../css/style.css or the domain like above, nothing works. The weird thing is that if I comment out the lines referencing the CSS, my root files will still be correctly displayed, even though they never reference the CSS file other than in the header. Does this have something to do with the .js files? I have no idea how they work and I havent touched them. Thanks!

Comment: check avery tag our <tag>on your header men

Answer (score 2):

You have problem here

```
<noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mywebsite.com/css/skel-noscript.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mywebsite.com/css/style.css" />
</noscript>
```

Remove `<noscript></noscript>`

And it should be like

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mywebsite.com/css/skel-noscript.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mywebsite.com/css/style.css" />
```

and move you `JS` files below `CSS`

Comment: anything between the `<noscript></noscript>` tags will only be used in case javascript is disabled or not working in the browser, so that makes sense. If you disable javascript those CSS files should be loaded (that's an easy test you can make)

Comment: I did the test and if the css inside `<noscript></noscript>` its not loading would you like to see?

Comment: Okay, I did that but now it's screwed up differently. The root files have some odd issues like the header text in one of the paragraphs shifted down, and on the store's page all of the formatting is practically gone. My header logo is no longer centered and quick-select bar (home, about us, store etc) has no formatting at all. the CSS folder contains several files, not sure if that's an issue. skel-noscript.css, style.css, style-1000px.css, style-desktop.css, style-mobile.css.

Comment: all above mention issues,  clearly means that one css property is over riding other, so you have to remove the unnecessary css and looks like you have 5 css files, can you share the link for me to have close look

Comment: Actually, I had forgotten to move the JS files below it, but I did so now the root files are fine. The store is however still screwed up.

Comment: Got it, give me a moment

Comment: sorry, was busy answering another question, i see there are css missing files, console shows error and also in view page source i see this ` </body>
</html>` you can't just declare these again and again, also top of your page, you are declaring `<html>` multiple times and its all messed up

Comment: yes you're right and I fixed the `<html>` issue. I don't see why /store/storehome.php isn't correctly receiving the CSS however. It's better than it was, but still messed up.

Comment: the css files which still missing add `/` like this, it's called absolute path e.g like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">` and `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style-desktop.css">`

Answer (score 0):

Late, but nevertheless... Looking at your header, the only css loaded comes from google. The other two are within noscript, so where are you getting your css from in the first place?